# C++ Concurrent modification and read of a single global variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a single public variable in a class

bool toSwitch = false;

```
Func_Thread1()
{
   if(toSwitch)
   {
      .....
      ....
      toSwitch = false;
   }
}
```

and

```
Func_Thread2()
{
   toSwitch = true;
}
```

The `Func_Thread1` will get called frequently(2 seconds once) and during certain interval `Func_Thread2` will get called(1 minute once) and change the global variable to true. So at the next `Func_Thread1` call the if condition will become true.

Does the `toSwitch` needs synchronization as it can read and modified by different threads concurrently ..?

**Update 2:**

What happens in this environment...?

```
 Func_Thread1()
    {
       if(toSwitch)
       {
          .....
          ....
       }
       else
       {
         ...
       }
    }
```

and

```
Func_Thread2()
{
   if(toSwitch)
   {
    toSwitch = false;
   }
   else
   {
     toSwitch = true;
   }
}
```

Does sync needs here , where one thread modifies and other thread reads the value of that global variable .?

Answer (score 3):

If an object is accessed by more than one thread and at least one thread is a writer that is a data race.

You need synchronization for the following reasons:

1. For the compiler to not reorder your reads and writes around access to the shared variable.
2. For other threads to see updates to this variable in consistent (atomic) and timely (flush the store buffer to the cache) fashion.

Your hardware is likely to be able to store a `bool` in atomic fashion, however, for the remaining reasons above you may like to use `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: Synchronization does not actually affect the timeliness of visibility propagation. In fact, this concept isn't normatively standardized at all (there's only a pleading note asking implementations to please propagate updates if they don't mind). Synchronization only affects relative *ordering*.

Comment: I dont want other thread to see the update in atomic fashion .. let it see at the next call.. If so any issues there?

Comment: @KerrekSB You are mistaken. Read http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy.html for more details.

Comment: @RahulJain By _constent (atomic)_ I mean that you do not observe data partially updated. _let it see at the next call_ that means you do not care about timeliness.

Comment: Can u please tell what is the partially updated data.. ? It is just a boolean with 'true' and 'false'

Comment: Ya.. i dont care about timeliness.. If at first call it is giving "false" (which is wrong) , at the next call i will get the changed value .. rite?

Comment: @RahulJain Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks.. So my last question to u is.. For synchronizing a map read and write from two threads, if i am not worried about timeliness, Which is faster (for my case) ..? Going with a mutex/CriticalSection Or with a atomic_bool and synchronize manually ?

Comment: @RahulJain An atomic write is likely to be faster, than atomic write for locking the mutex, followed by non-atomic write to bool, followed by an atomic write for unlocking the mutex.

Comment: @RahulJain, you MUST use atomic here. (or other form of synchronization). Without it, compiler might simply see that toSwich is never modified in the thread of execution and abandon your if statement altogether. You might get away with simple volatile, but this is very ill-advised. atomic writes vs. mutex lock/write/mutex unlock are likely to produce the same speed on uncontested mutex, but in contested mutexes atomic writes will be faster,

Comment: the Update2 also needs synchronized??  I am not considered on the perfection in entering the if blocks in thread 1. It is ok if it enters the if block correctly on the next call after the thread 2 changes the boolean

Comment: The problem is that not using synchronization results in undefined behavior.  It may well "work" reliably for you. It probably will. But It might work until the compiler or the operating system is updated. If might work until next tuesday and then decide to jump into the disk format function instead. It probably won't.. But nothing in the language says it will work. There is a simple way to tell the compiler what you are doing so it can always do the right thing, and that is to use synchronization. It's what it's for!

Comment: @RahulJain Based on everything that you read here, what do you think?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: The Update 2 is different case(where only one thread changes the boolean) .. the Update 2 model  is followed in one of our development project and that is working fine till now.. (without sync) .. Hence a confirmation

Comment: @RahulJain It is a [data race by definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races), hence you need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You need synchronization. Unsynchronized access to a shared memory location (`toSwitch`) from more than one thread where at least one access is a write (`toSwitch = true;`) constitutes a data race, which makes the behaviour of your program undefined.